# How to handle version control for embbedded system developement

Tags: git, version-control, buildroot

I am starting with my first real project for developing an embedded system consisting of multiple components. Namely these are uboot for the bootloader, buildroot for kernel and userland and a custom application which should be installed onto the system.

The key question is how I should handle the version control of the different components.

The desired folder structure I have in mind looks somewhat like this:

```
- mainproject
  - bootloader
    - configs
      - someFiles.cfg
    - uboot                   [Git Repo]
      - .config
      - otherUbootFiles
    - crosstool-ng            [Git Repo]
  - os
    - buildroot [Git Repo]
    - buildrootOutOfTreeFiles
    - targetfs
      - someFiles.txt
  - application
    - application1            [Git Repo]
    - application2            [Git Repo]
    - userdata
      - someFiles.txt
```

The mainproject should contain all files which are needed to completely generate the embedded system.
What I have in mind is a solution to be able to simply bump the integrated repositories to a new version if I want to update the version of e.g. uboot or buildroot.
Uboot and buildroot both store configurations inside their folders. When I include those repositories as submodules with git I can only track changes inside these folders within the corresponding repository. I would like to include these config files in my main repository but without loosing the ability to pull new versions for uboot and buildroot from git.

How would you go about version management for the given use case?
I am open for all kinds of suggestion, the only limitation is that git should be used for source and version control.

Comment: have you considered using symbolic links to outside the submodules?

Comment: Do you mean to create a symbolic link inside the main repository which points to the files I want to include from the subrepositories? I have not tried that yet.

Comment: I was thinking of creating symbolic links within the submodules that points to inside the main repository.